# Adding title to has-feedback span in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any good solution for adding title to feedback icon in forms in bootstrap?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="GET">
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="lastname">Last name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="lastname">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code adds little red cross inside input field. Now I want to add title of this span (that shows up on hover) and change its cursor. What is the simplier way to do that?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="GET">
 <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="lastname">Last name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="lastname">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Make a snippet code and make your question more relevant

Comment: Are you using this with a validation library (if so add the code) or this is how the input always is??

Comment: There is no validation library. Input always stays like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<span
    title="This field is required"
    style="pointer-events: all; cursor: help;"
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"
></span>
```

The trick is to overwritte the CSS attribute value `pointer-events: none;` that comes with the class *.form-control-feedback* :

`pointer-events: all`

#### Result:

[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2avrgh0L/1/

Answer (score 0):

**Updated solution :**

Since jquery selectors are not able to tag the span with bootstrap classes, I created another span on top of the 'x' icon and added script to target that. Seems to do the job as expected.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="GET">
    <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="lastname">Last name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
             <span id="test" style="position: relative;float:right;width:auto;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="lastname">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>            
        </div>

    </div>
</form>

$("#test").hover(function()
{
  $(this).attr("title","Click To Close");
  $(this).css("cursor","wait");
});
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6gmwhtbf/3/

Comment: I updated my question. Problem is, that in bootstrap span appears inside input. Adding title attribute doesn't work.